# Google Cloud Storage SDK(Java) randomly calling IP addersses instead of covering that call with google domain

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client

I'm using Google Storage SDK to download and upload files in Google bucket. I have also whitelisted **.googleapis.com** and ***.google.com** domains. But some of the calls from SDK are calling IP address(Owned by Google) directly like  https://216.58.220.10 because of that my network is restricting that call.

Is there a way so that I can configure something in Storage SDK so that it should call only those APIs which are covered with google domain. I have restrictions on my firewall so that data packets from random IP addresses should not get transferred.

Reference:
[It shows the call to googleapis and random IP(Owned by Google) address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWLVX.png)

Answer (score 0):

That IP address is not "random".  It's a Google-owned IP.  I found out by looking up the reverse mapping for it.  (In my case, I used the `host` command on my system, you can use other ways).

```
$ host 216.58.220.10
10.220.58.216.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer bom05s05-in-f10.1e100.net.
10.220.58.216.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer bom05s05-in-f10.1e100.net.
10.220.58.216.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer bom05s05-in-f10.1e100.net.
10.220.58.216.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer bom05s05-in-f10.1e100.net.
```

1e100.net is owned by Google:

```
$ whois 1e100.net
...
Registrant Organization: Google Inc.
Registrant State/Province: CA
Registrant Country: US
```

Mathematically 10^100, or 1E100 is sometimes referred to as a "[googol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol)".

Comment: Yes. That's what I also checked using IP locator, it shows that all those IP addresses are owned by Google. But these requests are not covered with google domain that is why they're getting blocked by Firewall. –

Comment: Are you saying that you're only able to whitelist a single domain?  That seems rather limiting (and also counter to what you said in your question).  If that's the case, you seem to have no alternative.

Comment: No. I have whitelisted *.googleapis.com and *.google.com. Do I need to whitelist all the IP addresses owned by Google? Or is there a way so that the request coming to or going from my network should gets covered with the domain name?

Comment: I don't know.  If it's not documented anywhere, that seems like an implementation detail that could change at any time.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been addressed as a [Public Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/123456218) of Google Cloud Platform, and considered intended behaviour. Since it is not a bug, it will not be fixed. The GC Storage SDK accesses Google-owned IP addresses that may change unpredictably and a firewall config or proxy needs to consider this.